# Writing a model for fitting an improper integral

Tags: fitting

I am very new to fitting functions in mathematica and I have to fit an improper integral to data. I can import .csv file, but I cannot make a model.

Here are the definitions of functions:

```
e[t_] := E^(-t^2/w^2)*E^(-I*t*o);
eS[t_] := Conjugate[e[t]];
inten[t_] = e[t]*eS[t]
```

And I have a model which is a sum of improper integrals - here are some of them. Where is my mistake? Is this the correct way to write models?

```
model = {
    4*NIntegrate[inten[u]*inten[u - t], {u, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}] + 
     4*NIntegrate[(inten[u] + inten[u - t])*
        Re[e[u]*eS[u - t]], {u, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Introduction

I copied your equations as presented by **yohbs**

```
e[t_] := Exp[-t^2/w^2 - I*t*o];
eS[t_] = Simplify@ComplexExpand@Conjugate[e[t]];
inten[t_] = Simplify@ComplexExpand[e[t]*eS[t]];
integrand = 
  Simplify@ComplexExpand[
    4*inten[u]*inten[u - t] + 2*inten[u]^2 + 
     2*Re[e[u]*e[u]*eS[u - t]*eS[u - t]] + 
     4*(inten[u] + inten[u - t])*Re[e[u]*eS[u - t]]];
```

and performed the integration

```
model = Integrate[integrand, {u, -∞, ∞}]
```

which resulted in

```
E^(-(t^2/w^2)) Sqrt[π]
  Abs[w] (2 + E^(t^2/w^2) + 4 E^(t^2/(4 w^2)) Cos[o t] + Cos[2 o t])
```

an equivalent expression is

```
Sqrt[π]Abs[w] (1 + (4 Cos[o t])/E^((3 t^2)/(4 w^2)) +
                   (2 + Cos[2 ot])/E^(t^2/w^2))
```

I imported your data from your csv file. Below is a plot of the data.

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 10}}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A careful look shows that the data is not quite symmetrical about zero.

The edges asymptote to a value that is approximately 1.2 (i.e., when `w` get's large).

An expanded view of the data close to the origin shows the cyclic nature.

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {0, 10}}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By counting the peaks observe that the range -14 to -2 represents five periods so the approximate frequency of this wave is:

```
Solve[ω (14 - 2) == 10. π, ω]

(* {{ω -> 2.61799}} *)
```

The maximum value of the data is about 8.

The model evaluated at zero becomes

```
model /. t -> 0

(* 8 Sqrt[π] Abs[w] *)
```

Which implies that `w` is approximately

```
Solve[8 Sqrt[π] w == 8., w]

(* {{w -> 0.56419}} *)
```

However, this value don't fit at all. `w` also controls the envelope around the data.

```
Plot[model /. {w -> 0.56, o -> 2.6}, {t, -10, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {All, Full}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The envelope is so thin that one can't see the cyclic data.

To get the correct envelope shape we need `w` to be approximately 80.

Below I have plotted the model data (two scales) with data adjusted so that the magnitude matches.

```
Module[
 {
  w = 80,
  o = 2.6,
  max,
  data2 = data
  },
 max = 8 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Abs[w];
 data2[[All, 2]] = data2[[All, 2]]*max/8;
 Column[{
   Show[
    Plot[E^(-(t^2/w^2)) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
       Abs[w] (2 + E^(t^2/w^2) + 4 E^(t^2/(4 w^2)) Cos[o t] + 
        Cos[2 o t]) ,
      {t, -150, 150},
     PlotStyle -> Black,
      PlotRange -> {Automatic, Full},
     ImageSize -> 400
     ],
    ListPlot[data2, PlotStyle -> Red,
      PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, Full}]
    ],
   Show[
    Plot[E^(-(t^2/w^2)) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
       Abs[w] (2 + E^(t^2/w^2) + 4 E^(t^2/(4 w^2)) Cos[o t] + 
        Cos[2 o t]) ,
      {t, -150, 150},
     PlotStyle -> Black,
      PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, Full},
     ImageSize -> 400
     ],
    ListLinePlot[data2, PlotStyle -> Red,
      PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, Full}]
    ]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that when we get the frequency approximately correct, `o` ≈ 2.6, there is a phase shift between the data and the model.

The amplitudes are off by a factor of around 140 and there appears to be a slight skew to the envelope (i.e, not symmetrical about the origin)

### New Model

In the new model we remove the term `Sqrt[π] Abs[w]` and introduce a new parameter, `scale`. We introduce a second new parameter, `offset` to account for the asymptote values.

Finally a time shift parameter, `ts` is used to account for the asymmetry about the origin and the phase shift.

The new model is:

```
model2 = scale ( (4 Cos[o (t - ts)])/E^((3 (t - ts)^2)/(4 w^2)) +
                 (2 + Cos[2 o (t - ts)])/E^((t - ts)^2/w^2) )   + offset
```

or

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`NonlinearModelFit` is used fit the data (I supplied starting values from experimentation).

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model2,
           {{o, 2.6}, {offset, 1.15}, {scale, 1}, {ts, 11.5}, {w, 80}}, t]

fit["BestFitParameters"]

(* {o -> 2.60488, offset -> 1.27066, scale -> 0.977271, 
 ts -> 11.3441, w -> 78.7623} *)
```

Below is a plot of the results.

```
Column[{
  Show[
   Plot[fit[t] ,
     {t, -345, 345},
    PlotStyle -> Black,
     PlotRange -> {Automatic, Full},
    ImageSize -> 400
    ],
   ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red,
     PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, Full}]
   ],
  Show[
   Plot[fit[t],
     {t, -150, 150},
    PlotStyle -> Black,
     PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, Full},
    ImageSize -> 400
    ],
   ListLinePlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red,
     PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, Full}]
   ]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The new model fits the data much better than the original model.

Comment: @10001000101111 See if the new model makes sense to you. Also you can look at examples for `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: This it a great answer - thank you! I thought that the difficulty in fitting the model was caused by the lack of pre-exponetial factor and I think that your scale parameter fixes that. I've noticed the shift (asymmetry) and I tried to accommodate for it while fitting in Origin Lab (which I'm more familiar with). But your solution works great

Answer (score 2):

1) Mathematica always tries to get the most generic solutions. However, often these are too generic. You should probably tell mathematica that `t`,`w`,`o` are real numbers, if they are. In that case `inten` has a very simple form, which is a Gaussian. For this you can use `ComplexExpand[inten[t]]`, or set `$Assumptions` accordingly.

2) The integral can be done analytically, so there's no need to use `NIntegrate`.

Altogether:

```
$Assumptions = Element[w | t | o, Reals];
e[t_] := Exp[-t^2/w^2 - I*t*o];
eS[t_] = Simplify @ ComplexExpand @ Conjugate[e[t]];
inten[t_] = Simplify @ ComplexExpand[e[t]*eS[t]];
integrand = 
 4 Simplify @ ComplexExpand[
    inten[u]*inten[u - t] + (inten[u] + inten[u - t])*
      Re[e[u]*eS[u - t]]
    ]
model = Integrate[integrand, {u, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

---

### Edit

As I wrote in the comments, the model is not a good model for the data and the fitting is very difficult due to the rapid oscillations, but it still gives something:

```
data = Import["https://fs05n3.sendspace.com/dl/4ff87464123001f76123bfd144d26228/593fff8f3d88ae41/sxu5n8/data.csv"]
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {w, o}, t]
Plot[fit[x],{x,-300,300}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have two questions:
1) I thought that NIntegrate is faster, isn't that true?
2) I'm trying to fit this model to data: (fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {w, o}, t]), but it gives me an error "earch specification 97 without variables should be a list with 1 to 4 \
elements". What is going on?

Comment: (a) NIntegrate might be faster or slower, depends on what you're integrating. Here I'd use Integrate because you only need to preform the integration once in the beginning of the calculation and have an analytic result which is valid for all `w`, `t`, etc that you don't have to recalculate at each iteration. (b) you will need to provide more code and the data you want to fit to in order for us to help you with that.

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/uecg1r

Here is the code. I thought that perhaps I should add another parameter in front of the gauss for fitting, but first it would have to give something other than error.

Comment: There is a problem in the notebook with the `data`. One is not able to get all of it. There is a printed output with a subset of the data showing. You need to take other measures to get the data to users. Maybe save it to an <xxx>.mx file and share that link.

Comment: I would advise against that. Try to simplify your problem as much as possible by creating a minimal working example that shows the problem. The actual original data is of little use since this is probably a simple syntax problem

Comment: https://www.sendspace.com/file/sxu5n8
Here is the whole data file.
I had tried simplifying the problem before, but I am new to this and generating data to fit the improper integrals had been more difficult than trying the model on real data

Comment: a) Your data does not look like the model you're trying to fit to -  it has a DC bias (i.e. for large t it goes to a constant different than 0). (b) You're trying to fit a rapidly oscillating function with a slowly oscillating envelope, which is very difficult unless your data is perfect. I would try to look in Fourier space to see if the data makes more sense there.

Comment: To conclude, this question has little to do with Mathemtica and more with curve fitting in general.

Comment: @yohbs But if the model is without syntax errors and there is data shouldn't it output a curve even if it doesn't fit the data well? Why does it give the error message? Did you encounter the same problem?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error message. I'll update my answer